Connect several models with relation based on type
I want to connect several models by hasMany relation based on their type. It should be like tangible example in the Eloquent docs but I need to connect these models between each other, not with one "Tag" model. What I tried now it is base class ConnectableModel and several model for connect. My table scheme looks like:
Tables:
connectables:
 - id
 - connectable_id
 - connectable_type
 - connected_id 
 - connected_type

filters: 
 - id

operations:
 - id

data: 
 - id

Parent model to use as base class for any "connectable" model:
abstract class ConnectableModel extends MyModel
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function args(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(static::class, 'connectable', null, 'id', 'id', 'id', 'id');
    }

    public function connectable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

Pivot:
class Connectable extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        /**
         * Connected to: -> <connected_id> of type <connected_type>
         */
        'connected_id',
        'connected_type',
        /**
         * What is connected: <connectable_id> of type <connectable_type> ->  
         */
        'connectable_id',
        'connectable_type'
    ];

    public function connectable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

Models I want to be connected:
class Filter extends ConnectableModel
{}
class Operation extends ConnectableModel
{}
class StrategyData extends ConnectableModel
{}

In tests I have something like that:
        $data1 = new StrategyData([
            'strategy_id' => $strategy->id, 
            'data_type_key' => StrategyDataEnum::Number, 
            'value' => 50
        ]);
        $data2 = new StrategyData([
            'strategy_id' => $strategy->id, 
            'data_type_key' => StrategyDataEnum::Number, 
            'value' => 100
        ]);
        $input1 = new Input([
            'strategy_id' => $strategy->id, 
            'input_type_key' => InputEnum::Value
        ]);
        $input2 = new Input([
            'strategy_id' => $strategy->id, 
            'input_type_key' => InputEnum::Value
        ]);
        $operation = new Operation([
            'strategy_id' => $strategy->id, 
            'operation_type_key' => OperationEnum::DiffPercentage
        ]);
        $filter = new Filter([
            'strategy_id' => $strategy->id, 
            'filter_type_key' => FilterEnum::Less
        ]);

        $data1->save();
        $data2->save();
        $input1->save();
        $input2->save();
        $operation->save();
        $filter->save();

        $data1->refresh();
        $data2->refresh();
        $input1->refresh();
        $input2->refresh();
        $operation->refresh();
        $filter->refresh();

        $input1->args()->attach($data1);
        $input2->args()->attach($data2);
        $operation->attach($input1);
        $operation->attach($input2);
        $filter->attach($operation);

For code above I've got error: 'message' => 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'connectable_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into connectables (connectable_type, id) values (App\Models\Strategies\Input, 15))'
